# Good / Bad idea to start a pull request in the beginning of a project

Tags: git

The current workflow we have in place at my company with regards to git is:

- Develop on a branch
- Push every so often
- When done developing, open a pull request in Github

We have a reviewers on that pull request where they comment suggestions for improvement. However a lot of the changes they are requesting can be made earlier in the development cycle, rather than waiting till im finished.

I am suggesting to the team lead that the workflow should be different. Rather than waiting till I have finished my code until other developers comment, wouldnt it make more sense for them to comment while im developing? I think this would catch many bugs earlier in the dev cycle.

What are the pros and cons of this approach? Is this a bad idea?

Suggested workflow:

- I create a new pull request when I start a new project
- Lets say I add some code and push
- I comment on the pull request asking the reviewers what they think of the change.
- They comment back and I implement the change

Comment: Is Github your only means of communication?

Comment: Communication related to code ? Yes. Not related to code? We use email, slack, daily standups via phone call etc

Comment: I'm not a fan of using Pull Requests internally within an organization, unless the organization has multiple departments, development teams or geographical locations.  The whole point of a Pull Request is to allow someone *from the outside* to submit code.  Some organizations do this for *code review* purposes, as the Pull Request provides a "staging area" for the code to be reviewed by another developer or supervisor prior to being committed to the main trunk.

Comment: GitHub introduced [draft pull requests](https://github.blog/2019-02-14-introducing-draft-pull-requests/) to handle this.

Comment: Wow! Nice, this is exactly what I needed. Just wonder why it isnt available in bitbucket (although original question  asks about github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to find issues early. No, you do not need pull requests for code review.

Fixing defects have exponential cost. The sooner you find them and fix an issue, the cheaper it can be. Thus, you want to detect problems as you type. Heck, you want to prevent typing them in the first place.

There is an argument for front loading all the work: Let us push all the effort into requirement engineering, architecture, and design. Because the more problems we can find there the better. *Cascade advocates, if any, would be on this camp.*

There is a counter argument: Let us do cycles. If we break our project into many small projects, then perhaps the cost of fixing issues does not go up too high. *Agile advocates belong here.*

Ignoring what approach handles changes in requirements better, and which can deliver more on a constrained dead line (which are enough arguments to pick one over the other). I do not think there is strong evidence on which leads to less cost fixing defects.

---

Alright, let us say we break the project into cycles. We still want to find issues early in the cycle.

Let us put methodologies to do that into two buckets:

- Automated methodologies

  The best we can do is find issues as you type: Have a configurable static analysis tool, one where your team can pick, and even create, rules that will be checked without compiling the code. *Depending on the language, runtime and platform, there might not be a good one. Still worth looking for one.*

  *There is also an argument for picking an statically typed language.*

  You will also have feedback when compiling. Assuming your static analysis does not catch thing as you type, or you do not have such tool… The compiler should be able to find some mistakes.

  Once your code compiled, you can run automated tests. Which means you would want to write tests. Which, I remind you, should be based on the requirements. *Oh, and tests might also be created in response to user issues.*

  You still want to be able to find issues in runtime, thus you would want logs and automated reports. Plus, you should also consider information security, but let us not talk about that.
- Manual methodologies

  You want clear guidelines and conventions, that the developer who writes the code should follow. And these would prevent bugs (and make help in making the software secure). *In fact, you want to convert this guidelines into static analysis rules, if possible.*

  Next, you want a second programmer looking at your code. And, since we would want to find issues early, we would want that other programmer looking as you type. That is, you would want pair programming. *Which, given the circumstances, might not be viable.*

  Then you resource to code review.

  Does that really require a pull request? No, it does not. It only requires that you code is visible you tell people to review your code. I remind you that at some point in the past people did this by printing the code in paper and going over it with a highlighter.

  You would archive the equivalent by pushing to a branch that your coworkers can see and asking for a review. Of course, you want to communicate that you want a code review by means other than simply pushing to a branch where nobody might be looking. And that other means of communication might or might not be a pull request. And I'd suggest to don't use a pull request, let that be for request of change that come from outside of the development team.

  *However, at the end, that is something on which your team has to agree on.*

  Afterwards you want testers to come and try to find edge cases. *Which hopefully translate into new automated tests.* If it makes sense for the project, there might also be usability test, and so on.

  Finally, for everything that slipped through the cracks, you have the user submitting a bug report.

---

To reiterate, to "catch many bugs earlier in the dev cycle", which is something you want to do, and should want to do... Code review is not the only tool. Plus for code review, there is no need to depend on pull requests. At the end, you should get to an agreement with your team. It is better asking them than us.

Comment: Interesting, I like the peer review idea because it really reinforces the fact that someone else has to review your code. What better way of doing that by coming up with the code together.  We do have static code checks in place but the issue is in dynamically typed languages all that can offer you are enforcing semantics like proper spacing or indentation and it doesn't enforce types.

Comment: @vi_ral There could still be a few things to do in a dynamically typed languages, for example some static analysis tools use code annotations to get a bit more done in such languages, you may also be interested in using fuzz testing to find bugs. Depending on your team, there might also be a chance of setting up pair programming by sharing screen over a video call. However I'd expect that to be harder to get traction.